# how can i search by name in CompanyCurrency table in Quickbooks online api

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

When i try to query this " Select Name from CompanyCurrency" i get this error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLydZ.png)

And If i Query by Code i get a result like this (Select Code from CompanyCurrency):

[Results by selecting the name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqeWJ.png)

Well , i don't know why is this happening because both code and name are properties in the table , any way i wanted to skip this issue by searching on the code so i've did the search query using like operator and it faults even the same query on all the other tables on the quickbooks online works fine .

any one knows the issue that related with this table ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can filter the results of that query. Looking at the [Manage multiple currencies docs](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0200_dev_guides/accounting/0065_manage_multiple_currencies) like they do on other endpoints, it doesn't list any fields as filterable. You should retrieve the list and just select the one you need in your code.